# Embed MS Word as editor (like in Outlook)

Tags: c#, ms-word

In Outlook you can use Word as your editor for emails (not sure what the situation is in Office 2007, but you can in 2003)

Is it possible for me to replicate this in my own app? I've seen an article mentioning using the Web Browser component, opening a .doc file and turning on the right toolbars but I'm not sure if this is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an ActiveX control to host Word in your application. [This article [msdn]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311765) can help you start, even though it is written for classic C++ and not C#. [This page [msdn]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973200.aspx) has some details on ActiveX/Windows Forms interoperability.