# Is there any word viewer plugin available for .NET 4.0 WinForms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0, ms-word

We developing an Application using .NET Framework 4.0  (C#) windows forms based application. Now, i want to show a word document's particular page in my application windows form with the same formatting in the original word document.Is there any way to show my word document's in C# Windows form based application...

How i do it?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864845/embed-ms-word-as-editor-like-in-outlook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way I know is to embed a WebBrowser control and set the URL to the document path.

Additional Infos:

- Add a `WebBrowser` Control to a form
- Insert `webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"C:\doc\MyDoc.doc");` somewhere
- Important constraint: IE and Word must be installed properly

Comment: Thanks Matthias Alleweldt : can you explain little bit more? I am new to .Net.

Comment: @Saravanan: I added some informations

Comment: @Matthias :Thanks for your reply.But in my form, i have only one web browser control and one command button.In Command1 click, i wrote your code, webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"C:\doc\MyDoc.doc");It will open that word document using MS-Word without shown in the Web Browser Box.And also In web browser box "Navigation of the webpage was canceled"What i do?

Comment: how to open MS-Word Document within the form itself...i mean with in the C# Form's any possible component(control)? Plese give me a way to get this...

Comment: @Saravanan: With MS Word installed or not?

Comment: @Matthias Alleweldt:yes, With MSWord Installed...